# Disable toucesMoved on UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView on which I am adding multiple UIImages on multiple click of a button and moving it with the help of TouchesMoevd.
The problem is whenever I move the UIimage it moves through out the UIView.

I want my image to move only in UIImageView.

I know it is easy but I dont know how to restrict the image motion in particular portion???

help ...

here is my code og TouchesMoved Method.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
imgPimple = (UIImageView*)[touch view];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[imgPimple superview]];
imgPimple.clipsToBounds = YES;
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])

    {
        imgPimple.center = touchLocation;
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have resolved this problem

solution is: this code in toucesMoved method

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];


imgPimple = (UIImageView*)[touch view];


CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[image superview]];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(15, 20, 280, 220), touchLocation)) 
{
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])

    {
        imgPimple.center = touchLocation;
    }
}
```